# Android Studio appcompat and firebase Version failing

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Problem with Android Studio or Android itself (?).
I want to include ad Mob in my App and followed the instructions on the Android Developer site.
So my Problem is that I can't compile firebase as shown on the picture:
[with firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE8WS.png)

This happens only if I add this specific firebase line as shown in the other screenshot.
[without firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LLTV.png)

Has anyone a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested changes:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Wow never thought that the solution is so simple :D 
Thank you :)